# Decode Base64 data what a scam

Tags: base64, decode

What a scam,
I've purcased a theme for wordpress and functions.php is Base64 encoded... no answers and 0 support and I can't customize it without accessing this data.

this is the file: http://pastebin.com/TQAe3dbE

and this is what I've decoded (putting echo instead of eval) but I don't know how to use it: http://pastebin.com/G7TEFr0V

This stuff is driving me crazy why encoding a piece of a theme which people buy?

Thanks for any hints,

Andrea

Comment: Shouldn't you fight this with the seller of the theme? What point is there in trying to hack a theme you paid for :/

Comment: I suspect that I won't receive any answer, that's because I'm going this way...

Comment: You probably won't receive any answers because instead of asking 'how can I decode this properly?', you start out with shouting 'scam'. This is no consumer-forum, it's for code-questions. If you _need_ it decoded, I'd advise a complete rewording of the actual question without the 'scam' - fluff.

Comment: Some other useful information would have been any information about the theme, such as its name, or a link to the theme's website.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP decode starting with $OOO000000=urldecode('%66%67%36%73%62%65%68%70%72%61%34%63](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700767/php-decode-starting-with-ooo000000-urldecode6667367362656870726134)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be a rant about a theme you bought and does not contain any real programming question.

Comment: I was bored, so I decoded it: http://pastebin.com/3YtiCeci

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately, there are free PHP testers which let us evaluate this type of code without putting our server at risk.  http://phptester.net/ would be one example, and putting the linked code in there, and progressively de-obfuscating it reveals some suspicious behavior.  I doubt this is a wordpress theme's functions.php file.

If anyone gets curious and feels like de-obfuscating further to see what this really is, here is my progress, which breaks down when it tries to start reading files, which is blocked by phptester.net.  Those offending lines are commented out below.

```
<?php
echo '<hr>';
echo $OOO0O0O00=__FILE__;
echo '<hr>';
echo $OOO000000=urldecode('%74%68%36%73%62%65%68%71%6c%61%34%63%6f%5f%73%61%64%66%70%6e%72');
echo '<hr>';
echo $OO00O0000=46112;
echo '<hr>';
echo $OOO0000O0=$OOO000000{4}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{3}.$OOO000000{5};
echo '<hr>';
echo $OOO0000O0.=$OOO000000{2}.$OOO000000{10}.$OOO000000{13}.$OOO000000{16};
echo '<hr>';
echo $OOO0000O0.=$OOO0000O0{3}.$OOO000000{11}.$OOO000000{12}.$OOO0000O0{7}.$OOO000000{5};
echo '<hr>';
echo $O0O0000O0='OOO0000O0';
echo '<hr>';
echo ((base64_decode('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')));
echo '<hr>';

echo '<hr>';
echo $OO0OO0000=$OOO000000{17}.$OOO000000{12}.$OOO000000{18}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{19};
echo '<hr>';
echo"if(!0) $O000O0O00=$OO0OO0000($OOO0O0O00,'rb')";
//if(!0)echo '<hr>'. $O000O0O00=$OO0OO0000($OOO0O0O00,'rb');
echo '<hr>';
echo $OO0OO000O=$OOO000000{17}.$OOO000000{20}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{16};
echo '<hr>';
echo $OO0OO00O0=$OOO000000{14}.$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{20}.$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{20};
echo '<hr>';
echo" $OO0OO000O($O000O0O00,1143)";
echo '<hr>';
//echo $OO0OO000O($O000O0O00,1143);
echo '<hr>';
echo "$OO00O00O0= ($OOO0000O0($OO0OO00O0($OO0OO000O($O000O0O00,380),'69iZQMGcN2XhDdFRs7/o3jwme0LVH5rux8PvYtKI1JAabUSWEkgOyTpnlzfC+4Bq=','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/')))";
echo '<hr>';
//echo $OO00O00O0= ($OOO0000O0($OO0OO00O0($OO0OO000O($O000O0O00,380),'69iZQMGcN2XhDdFRs7/o3jwme0LVH5rux8PvYtKI1JAabUSWEkgOyTpnlzfC+4Bq=','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/')));

echo '<hr>';
echo '<hr>';
echo base64_decode('69iZQMGcN2XhDdFRs7/o3jwme0LVH5rux8PvYtKI1JAabUSWEkgOyTpnlzfC+4Bq=');
```